# Overloading extraction operator for two classes

Tags: c++, extraction-operator

is it possible to write an extraction operator when reading from a file for member variables in two classes? The first class is CPerson, which contains name and EGN (social security number), and the second class is CStudent, which contains FN (faculty number) and a map with various tests (code of test and earned points). Currently I have overloaded an extraction operator for the class CStudent, which means that I have access to its private members, but I would like to do the same thing for CPerson, so I don't need to use setter functions for that class as well.

```
class CPerson
{
private:
    string name;
    string EGN;

public:
    CPerson(const string n, const string e)
    {
        name=n;
        EGN=e;
    }
    void setname(const string n) {name=n;}
    void setEGN(const string e) {EGN=e;}
};

class CStudent: public CPerson
{
private:
    string FN;
    map<int, int> st_tests;

public:
    CStudent(const string o, const string p, const string n):CPerson(o,p)
    {FN=n;}
    friend istream &operator>> (istream &, CStudent &);
};

istream &operator>> (istream &input, CStudent &c)
{
    string z, x, y, line;
    int d, e;

    getline(input,line);
    istringstream ln(line);
    ln >> z >> x >> c.FN;
    c.setname(z);
    c.setEGN(x);

    while(true)
    {
        ln >> d >> e;
        c.st_tests[d] = e;
        if(!ln.good())
            break;
    }
    return input;
}

class CGroup
{
private:
    string spec; //specialty
    int kurs; //course
    int grupa; //group
    vector<CStudent> students; //vector of CStudent objects

public:
    CGroup(const string filename) //constructor with name of file to be read as parameter
    {
        string a;
        int b, c;
        ifstream st;
        st.open(filename.c_str(),ios::in);
        if(!st)
        {
            cout<<"Cannot open "<<filename<<" or file does not exist."<<endl;
            exit(1);
        }
        string line;
        getline(st,line);
        istringstream group(line);
        group >> a >> b >> c;
        spec = a;
        kurs = b;
        grupa = c;
        while(!st.eof())
        {
            CStudent student;
            st >> student;
            students.push_back(student);
        }
        st.close();
    }
};
```

If it's needed, here are the contents in one of the files:

```
KST 1 1
Ivan 9404019382 61360125 1 55 2 90 3 78 12 82 13 99 14 78 15 72
Kaloqn 9311281029 61360126 1 82 2 43 3 95 13 50
Airqn 9408132918 61360127 1 91 2 40 3 89
Mariq 9409071824 61360128 1 55 2 91 3 78 16 0
Ginka 9312198212 61360129 1 87 2 84 3 15
Leika 9405221982 61360130 1 25 2 76 3 56
Shumaher 9305119225 61360131 1 94 2 75 3 92
Onzi 9408108876 61360132 1 40 2 59 3 49
```

Updated operators:

```
CPerson
{
    friend istream &operator>> (istream &, CPerson &);
};

istream &operator>> (istream &input, CPerson &c)
{
    input >> c.name >> c.EGN;
    return input;
}

istream &operator>> (istream &input, CStudent &c)
{
    int d, e;
    string line;
    getline(input,line);
    istringstream ln(line);
    ln >> static_cast<CPerson&>(c) >> c.FN;
    while(ln >> d >> e)
        c.st_tests[d] = e;
    return input;
}
```

Result:

```
Ivan 9404019382 61360125 1 55 2 90 3 78 12 82 13 99 14 78 15 72
Kaloqn 9311281029 61360126 1 82 2 43 3 95 12 82 13 50 14 78 15 72
Airqn 9408132918 61360127 1 91 2 40 3 89 12 82 13 99 14 78 15 72
Mariq 9409071824 61360128 1 55 2 91 3 78 12 82 13 99 14 78 15 72 16 0
Ginka 9312198212 61360129 1 87 2 84 3 15 12 82 13 99 14 78 15 72 16 0
Leika 9405221982 61360130 1 25 2 76 3 56 12 82 13 99 14 78 15 72 16 0
Shumaher 9305119225 61360131 1 94 2 75 3 92 12 82 13 99 14 78 15 72 16 0
Onzi 9408108876 61360132 1 40 2 59 3 49 12 82 13 99 14 78 15 72 16 0
```

Comment: There is no copy constructor for either CPerson or CStudent. Also I don't see a default constructor. I don't really know if that's a problem, I am just commenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read `name` and `EGN` in `CPerson`:

```
istream &operator>> (istream &input, CPerson &c)
{
    // this is friend function, so you can access private members of CPerson
    input >> c.name >> c.EGN; // or something similar...
    return input;
}
```

Extraction to `CStudent` will extract data to `CPerson` first (name and EGN should be your first strings in input data):

```
istream &operator>> (istream &input, CStudent &c)
{
    input >> static_cast<CPerson&>(c); // read CPerson's data first

    string line;

    if(getline(input, line))
    {
        istringstream iss(line);

        while(iss >> d >> e) // then read CStudent's special data
            c.st_tests[d] = e;
    }

    return input;
}
```

A few suggested improvements:

```
CStudent student; // you will need default constructor for this

while(st >> student)
    students.push_back(student); // read like this in CGroup
```

Pass `std::string` by `const&`. Restricting yourself with `const` in these parameters is almost to no use without reference.

```
CGroup(string const& filename);
CPerson(string const& n, string const& e)
```

Comment: I've done something wrong with the operators, which is causing an infinite loop. I've posted the updated operators at the bottom of the original post.

Comment: It seems that the issue is with the CGroup function. If I simply remove the st.eof() loop, it properly extracts all the information for the first student in every file. Unfortunatelly your suggested improvement for CGroup didn't have an effect.

Comment: @Arirang Well actually, you have to read with `std::getline` and `std::istringstream`, sorry about that. Try to adjust the functions and let me know if it works.

Comment: I've made the changes, but now it inserts tests to students in the group, which they usually don't have. Can I somehow flush the stream to prevent that from happening? I've updated the operator in the original post, as well as the result. Keep in mind that the students in the result are sorted based on their average points from their tests.

Comment: I just saw that you've updated your function using stringstream, but the results are the same.

Comment: Alright, I've found the problem causing the map of tests to be flooded with non-existent tests. Your suggested improvement for using while(st >> student) in the CGroup constructor was actually causing the issue. When I changed it back to the way it used to be before, with while(!st.eof()), it started reading the tests properly. Nonetheless, thank you very much for your help, I really had no idea how to have extraction operators for two classes.

Comment: You're welcome. I will try to find out what was wrong with it.